# Does jQuery.submit() narrow down the scope of DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Let's imagine that we have such code:

```
    $('form[name = "someName"]').submit(function() {
        var formInputValue = $('#inputId').val();
});
```

What will happen if there is another  element with the same id on the same page as this form? Does jQuery.submit() function narrow down the scope of DOM elements available when we are inside function()? If not, how to simply get values of inputs being inside particular form?

Comment: IDs **must** be unique. Period.

Comment: Ok. That's my mistake. To not distract attention let's assume that we are looking for input by name, not by ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Submit on Form id and your page have two form with same id. it work on first form Submit.

If you want same function for more then one form you can use this code

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    alert($(this).serialize());
    return false;
});
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EGjU3/)

Answer (score 2):

If you use ID's, jQuery will stop at the first element matching that ID on the DOM. You should perhaps look at using jQuery's [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) function or simply do:

```
$(this).serialize();
```

which will [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) your form.

Anyway, ID's should always be unique: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really

Answer (score 1):

If you need to access the data entered inside the form, consider calling `.serialize()` or `.serializeArray()`

Using the code you provided I guess jQuery will return the value of the first element found or an array with all values.

See the docs for further explanation:

https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

https://api.jquery.com/serialize/